# Is any thing wrong with my Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, raspberry-pi

I was just wondering if my code is wrong. I am running this on a Raspberry Pi and an Apache Server if the code looks good would it be my set up on how the code is on the Pi?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Three.js</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r69/three.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THEE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var Geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1,1,1 );
            var Mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( Geo, Mat );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );

                cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a problem in this line: var camera = new THEE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );. Change THEE to THREE.

Comment: Garrett, you say it looks OK, but does it work properly?  Does it do what you expect it to do?  What kind of tests have you tried to find out?  If you're not sure how to investigate whether your code is working right, then ask how to do that.  If it's not working right, then tell us how it's not working correctly.  If your code is working correctly, then this question might be more appropriate for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @wilsotobianco that helped do its thing. it was just the example code off the threejs.org website.

Comment: I am still a beginner at a lot of thing java script ill check or CodeReview @Mars

Comment: CodeReview is better after more experience. StackOverflow is the right place now.  You'll learn how to ask good questions with experience.

Comment: As long as the code is working as expected, you can post it on Code Review.  Just don't post broken or stub code, and you will be fine.  In fact, if your code is working but you want to know about improvements, Code Review is the place to go.